# Error while connecting to cluster using python

Tags: python, cassandra

I am using Cassandra via Dockers and i created node and when i start the node, it works fine and i am able to run queries using cqlsh too. But when i try to connect python (Pycharm) and cassandra it gives me error. Please give your suggestions what could be wrong. The contact point i have specified is one of my node ip. I have also checked the node and its up and running. I am unable to understand why it is giving me this error.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster= Cluster(contact_points=[ "172.17.0.2"],port=7000)
session=cluster.connect()
row= session.execute(
   """
   CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS demo WITH REPLICATION = {
       'class':SimpleStrategy,
       'replication_factor':3
   }
   """
   )
```

Error

```
session=cluster.connect()
 File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1247, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
 File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1283, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
 File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1270, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
 File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2773, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
 File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2816, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.17.0.2': ConnectionShutdown('Connection to 172.17.0.2 was closed',)})
```

[image: Cassandra node status]

Comment: What docker image are you running?

Comment: Can you do `docker exec -it cas1 cat <cassandra_path>/cassandra.yaml | grep CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS`

Comment: I ran this command and it gives me nothing. Just shows me the next cmd terminal.

Comment: Are you able to ping this IP from the host machine?

Comment: @user9371612 woops, my bad. I was looking at some env variables to the docker image. Try `docker exec -it cas1 cat <cassandra_path>/cassandra.yaml | grep listen_address `

Comment: I was able to ping but the cmd you gave me doesn't do anything yet and could you please tell me how the cmd  would help me?

Comment: @user9371612 You have to set the listen_address for the node to accept other connections than localhost